# SQL Server 2008 Sum and Select Max Only?

Tags: sql-server-2008, max, row-number

I am trying to understand how to do a Sum when I need to only use the Max/top values for a date period. This is kind of like [SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate) but not exactly. Thanks for reading.

```
declare @tbl Table ( tableid int , eventdate date,  valuec char(5) , valued int , recordedwhen datetime2(3) )
insert into @tbl values ( 0 , '2012-03-22' , '11111' , 3 , '2012-03-23 17:21:01.083' )
insert into @tbl values ( 1 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 3 , '2012-03-23 17:21:01.083' )
insert into @tbl values ( 2 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 4 , '2012-03-23 18:21:01.083' )
insert into @tbl values ( 3 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 5 , '2012-03-23 18:21:01.083' )

select 
        eventdate, valuec , sum(valued) as valuedSum , recordedwhen
        from 
        @tbl
        group by eventdate, valuec, recordedwhen
```

I get three rows. But what I actually want is this:

```
--   
--   eventdate  valuec valuedSum   recordedwhen
--   ---------- ------ ----------- ----------------------
--   2012-03-22 11111  3           2012-03-23 17:21:01.08
--   2012-03-22 22222  9           2012-03-23 18:21:01.08
```

I do not want the row where tableid=1 because that is part of an older batch of data.
The newer rows represent a later insert (all recordedwhen values with the same datetime are the same for a batch)

So if a new row was inserted like this:

```
insert into @tbl values ( 4 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 6 , '2012-03-24 18:21:01.083' )
```

Then the data would should like this:

```
--   eventdate  valuec valuedSum   recordedwhen
--   ---------- ------ ----------- ----------------------
--   2012-03-22 11111  3           2012-03-23 17:21:01.08
--   2012-03-22 22222  6           2012-03-24 18:21:01.08
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically need two selects. You can do either an inner select, or CTE. The following produces the result you desire

```
create table #tbl ( tableid int , eventdate date,  valuec char(5) , valued int , recordedwhen datetime2(3) )
insert into #tbl values ( 0 , '2012-03-22' , '11111' , 3 , '2012-03-23 17:21:01.083' )
insert into #tbl values ( 1 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 3 , '2012-03-23 17:21:01.083' )
insert into #tbl values ( 2 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 4 , '2012-03-23 18:21:01.083' )
insert into #tbl values ( 3 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 5 , '2012-03-23 18:21:01.083' )
insert into #tbl values ( 4 , '2012-03-22' , '22222' , 6 , '2012-03-24 18:21:01.083' )

;
with t (eventdate, valuec, maxrecordedwhen)
as (select eventdate, valuec, max(recordedwhen)
    from #tbl
    group by eventdate, valuec)
select t.eventdate, t.valuec, sum(valued) as valuedsum, maxrecordedwhen
from t
    join #tbl on t.eventdate = #tbl.eventdate and t.valuec = #tbl.valuec
where t.maxrecordedwhen = #tbl.recordedwhen
group by t.eventdate, t.valuec, t.maxrecordedwhen

drop table #tbl
```

Notice that the maximum batch date is found in the CTE and then used to filter the summation result.

Comment: This looks great. Still trying to understand why you added the Where clause instead of adding an additional Join condition, is there an optimization there I am not seeing?

Comment: I believe both would produce the same execution plan. It just made sense to me to use the `where` clause.