# How to capture the last execution date after a download from Mysql in Sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a question regarding the use of the Textbox in ASP.NET.

I have a download page with a button, so that when I click, the action of downloading data from a database(Mysql) to a database(Sql) is done. On the default page I have a TextBox field that has to display the last execution date of the download action.

How can i intercept that last execution date?

**default page:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       *// last execution date capture and display*
    }
}
```

**download page**

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string server = "XXX";
    string database = "XXX";
    string uid = "XXX";
    string password = "XX";
    bool convert =true;
    string MySqlConnStr = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";" + "ConvertZeroDateTime=" + convert +";";
    string SqlConnStr = "Data Source=XXX;" + "Initial Catalog=XXX;" + "User id=XXX;" + "Password=XX;";

    DataSet SqldSet = new DataSet(); // SqlServer Dataset that holds Sql Server data

    DataSet MySqldSet = new DataSet(); //MySql dataset that will be used to push data into MySql database

}
```

Comment: Please write a better title based on your specific problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC (I have removed the tag)

Comment: I think this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550703/sql-get-the-last-date-time-record

Comment: do you want to store the last execution date information to database and display every-time user opens the application? or just display during the session?

Comment: Do you require to know the historic datetime for downloads done after a page refresh, or do you only care about the downloads done in that session?

Comment: i want to display it every time user opens the application.

Comment: Why do you want to "display" information in `Textbox`? Textbox is to input field. You should choose a label or textblock to display info.  Also why are you trying to display last execution date in `Text_Changed` event? This event only fires when you input some text in the textbox.

Comment: just care about the downloads done in that session.

Comment: ok! great. so i should change the Textbox to label field. But the question is always how can i capture the download execution date and display it?

Comment: See my answer below. You should first query the `MSSQL` database to get the last updated value and assign it to the label.

Comment: Absolutely the worst title I've seen all month. How many questions a day do you think are about text boxes in ASP.NET?

Comment: Sorry guys for the title. this was my first ever post on this sites. and i am not english native. Hope i will do better the next time. thank u for answering at all.

Comment: @ANewGuyInTown can i know how wich method to use to catch that value in asp.net? how to implement the c# function i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  you want to know the date when it was last updated (i.e. when was the last time the `sql` table was uploaded information from `mysql`, then use the following query to retrieve the information from `MsSql` database.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
         WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'YourDatabase')
          AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TableNameThatGetsUpdatedOrInserted')
```

Assign the `last_user_update` value to the `label`.

Use the following C# code:

```
  public DateTime GetLastUpdatedDate()
        {
            string connectionString="";//your connection string to connect to Ms Sql database 
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = @" SELECT top 1 last_user_update
                                        FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
                                        WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'YourDatabase')
                                        AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TableNameThatGetsUpdatedOrInserted')";
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 60;
                    return (DateTime)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @AnewGyInTown. Thanks its works very well! to do the same operation in the opposite side (from Sql to Mysql) in a update query on Mysql, the variable cmd.CommandText should be modify in which way?

Answer (score 0):

for updates to the textbox when clicking the button

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy hh:MM:ss")
}
```

for the page load you'll have to get the datetime from the database and putting that in

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call to database
    TextBox1.Text = returned date.
}
```

Comment: an example of the call to database with Sql syntax please. is just a simple query?