# SQL Server query to join two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join

I've got a 2 part problem where through the use of google managed to find the answer to the first part at 
[SQL get the last date time record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550703/sql-get-the-last-date-time-record)

User **Osy** code work really well for me,

Osy's code below!

```
 select filename, dates, status 
 from yt a 
 where a.dates = (select max(dates)
                  from yt b
                  where a.filename = b.filename)
```

The query returns only the latest dates for each filename.

If I could just stick to the same example question as url above.

This is the table used in the example:

`yt` table:

```
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|filename |Dates                   |Status |
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|abc.txt  |2012-02-14 12:04:45.397 |Open   |
|abc.txt  |2012-02-14 12:14:20.997 |Closed |
|abc.txt  |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407 |Open   |
|dfg.txt  |2012-02-14 12:14:20.997 |Closed |
|dfg.txt  |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407 |Open   |
+---------+------------------------+-------+
```

The second part of the problem:

What I am now trying to achieve is that I have a second table and would like to join the results from the query above on the filename and return the user.

**Table2**

```
+--------+--------+
|filename |ref     |
+---------+--------+
|abc.txt  |Heating |
|dfg.txt  |Cooling |
+---------+---- ---+
```

Result that I am trying to achieve from the query is as follows, using Osy's code above to return only the latest for each entry per device, and then to display the **ref** column and not display the **filename**

Example:

```
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|ref      |Dates                   |Status |
+---------+------------------------+-------+
|Heating  |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407 |Open   |
|Cooling  |2013-02-14 12:20:59.407 |Open   |
+---------+------------------------+-------+
```

I can use a inner join directly on the yt table but cannot get is to 
combine (nest) with the code from Osy above.

Using SQL Server 2012. Please let me know if I left out anything.

Thank you.

Comment: you don't NEED to "nest" the join. just add a join statement to the parent/outer query as you would any other join.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "cannot get is to combine (nest) with the code from Osy above."?   Did you get an error?   Please post your attempt to do this, and what was wrong with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing with your posted example code, again perform one more `JOIN` with `Table2` like

```
select t2.ref, xx.Dates, xx.Status
from Table2 t2 join (
select filename, dates, status 
 from yt a where a.dates = (
 select max(dates)
 from yt b
 where a.filename = b.filename
)) xx on t2.filename = xx.filename;
```

Comment: Thank you Rahul, I managed to test out your query on my tables last night, before the power went out(thanx third world) had to re-do most of my work this morning. Updated code on  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93dcb/1)

Answer (score 1):

This might be faster way to do it.

```
SELECT  [ref],
        [dates],
        [status]
 FROM   (SELECT a.[filename],
                a.[dates],
                a.[status],
                t2.[ref],
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[filename] ORDER BY a.[dates] DESC) [Rn]
         FROM   yt a
                JOIN Table2 t2 ON a.[filename] = t2.[filename]
        ) t
 WHERE  t.Rn = 1
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. Thank you, gives me a different perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Speculating the bottom query but is should work:

```
SELECT a.ref, MAX(b.Dates), b.Status
FROM Table2 AS a INNER JOIN yt AS b ON a.ref=b.filename AND b.Status='Open'
GROUP BY a.ref, b.Status
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: This will give you 2 records for each `ref` since there are 2 `status` and the max `dates` for each status

Comment: Then Change the `INNER` to `RIGHT`

Comment: Dankie Steven, just had a quick go at your query, did not seem to return the result. will have another go at it tomorrow and update my comment. thanks for your time.

Comment: No Problem. Jamie's solution works but is a deprecated method as of MS Sql Server 2003 when `JOIN` made an appearance. Using `JOINS` is much more robust and flexible.

Comment: Aslo here is a good explenation with examples of `JOINS` [link] (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/07/19/671712.aspx)