# Select info from table where row has max date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, greatest-n-per-group

My table looks something like this:

```
group    date      cash  checks
  1    1/1/2013     0      0
  2    1/1/2013     0      800
  1    1/3/2013     0      700
  3    1/1/2013     0      600
  1    1/2/2013     0      400
  3    1/5/2013     0      200
```

-- Do not need cash just demonstrating that table has more information in it

I want to get the each unique group where date is max and checks is greater than 0. So the return would look something like:

```
group    date     checks
  2    1/1/2013    800
  1    1/3/2013    700
  3    1/5/2013    200
```

attempted code:

```
SELECT group,MAX(date),checks
    FROM table
    WHERE checks>0
    GROUP BY group
    ORDER BY group DESC
```

problem with that though is it gives me all the dates and checks rather than just the max date row.

using ms sql server 2005

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql?rq=1

Comment: avoid using special words like "group" as columns ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

```
SELECT group,MAX(date) as max_date
FROM table
WHERE checks>0
GROUP BY group
```

That works to get the max date..join it back to your data to get the other columns:

```
Select group,max_date,checks
from table t
inner join 
(SELECT group,MAX(date) as max_date
FROM table
WHERE checks>0
GROUP BY group)a
on a.group = t.group and a.max_date = date
```

Inner join functions as the filter to get the max record only.

FYI, your column names are horrid, don't use reserved words for columns (group, date, table).

Comment: Typo in `Select group,max_date,check` column name is "checks". got me confused a little what check is doing here.

Comment: +1, My table =>( ID, group_ID, DateColumn), I need to get the date value with Max(ID) with respect to group_ID.  It workd!

Answer (score 56):

You can use a [window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) MAX() like this:

```
SELECT
  *, 
  max_date = MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
FROM table
```

to get max dates per `group` alongside other data:

```
group  date      cash  checks  max_date
-----  --------  ----  ------  --------
1      1/1/2013  0     0       1/3/2013
2      1/1/2013  0     800     1/1/2013
1      1/3/2013  0     700     1/3/2013
3      1/1/2013  0     600     1/5/2013
1      1/2/2013  0     400     1/3/2013
3      1/5/2013  0     200     1/5/2013
```

Using the above output as a derived table, you can then get only rows where `date` matches `max_date`:

```
SELECT
  group,
  date,
  checks
FROM (
  SELECT
    *, 
    max_date = MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY group)
  FROM table
) AS s
WHERE date = max_date
;
```

to get the desired result.

Basically, this is similar to [@Twelfth's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19433107/297408) but avoids a join and may thus be more efficient.

You can try the method [at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be3f0/1).

Answer (score 5):

Using an `in` can have a performance impact. Joining two subqueries will not have the same performance impact and can be accomplished like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT msisdn
              ,callid
              ,Change_color
              ,play_file_name
              ,date_played
          FROM insert_log
         WHERE play_file_name NOT IN('Prompt1','Conclusion_Prompt_1','silent')
        ORDER BY callid ASC) t1
       JOIN (SELECT MAX(date_played) AS date_played
               FROM insert_log GROUP BY callid) t2
         ON t1.date_played = t2.date_played
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT distinct
  group, 
  max_date = MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY group), checks
FROM table
```

Should work.

Comment: Its not an answer. Please tell more informations about your query.

Comment: At this point, years after original question, this should be the top accepted answer. The WINDOW function is more efficient than the join, plus adding the DISTINCT gets the correct answer for the OP's questions, just add the WHERE checks>0.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss ... to answer your question, this is a basic DISTINCT select on the table. The table fields "group" & "checks" are unique, and the use of the window function gets max "date" for that group ("group" & "checks").

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (1, '1/1/2013', 0, 0),
        (2, '1/1/2013', 0, 800),
        (1, '1/3/2013', 0, 700),
        (3, '1/1/2013', 0, 600),
        (1, '1/2/2013', 0, 400),
        (3, '1/5/2013', 0, 200)
) x ([group], date, cash, checks);


-- Method 1
SELECT distinctgroup.[group],
       max_date.date,
       max_date.cash,
       max_date.checks
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT [group] FROM #temp) distinctgroup
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
           [group],
           date,
           cash,
           checks
    FROM #temp t
    WHERE distinctgroup.[group] = t.[group]
    ORDER BY date DESC
) max_date;



-- Method2

SELECT ot.[group],
        ot.date,
       ot.cash,
       ot.checks
       
FROM 
(SELECT  it.[group],
         it.date,
         it.cash,
         it.checks, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [group] ORDER BY date DESC) AS rownum 
FROM #temp it) ot
WHERE ot.rownum=1





DROP TABLE #temp;
```