# Select max date by grouping?

Tags: mysql, select, aggregate-functions, maxdate

PLEASE will someone help? I've put HOURS into this silly, stupid problem. [This stackoverview post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date) is EXACTLY my question, and I have tried BOTH suggested solutions to no avail.

Here are MY specifics. I have extracted 4 records from my actual database, and excluded no fields:

```
master_id   date_sent   type    mailing response
00001   2015-02-28 00:00:00 PHONE   NULL    NULL
00001   2015-03-13 14:45:20 EMAIL   ThankYou.html   NULL
00001   2015-03-13 14:34:43 EMAIL   ThankYou.html   NULL
00001   2015-01-11 00:00:00 EMAIL   KS_PREVIEW  TRUE
00001   2015-03-23 21:42:03 EMAIL   MailChimp Update #2 NULL
```

(sorry about the alignment of the columns.)

I want to get the most recent mailing and date_sent for each master_id. (My extract is of only one master_id to make this post simple.)

So I run this query:

```
SELECT master_id,date_sent,mailing
FROM contact_copy
WHERE type="EMAIL"
```

and get the expected result:

```
master_id   date_sent   mailing         
1   3/13/2015   14:45:20    ThankYou.html       
1   3/13/2015   14:34:43    ThankYou.html       
1   1/11/2015   0:00:00 KS_PREVIEW      
1   3/23/2015   21:42:03    MailChimp   Update  #2
```

BUT, when I add this simple aggregation to get the most recent date:

```
SELECT master_id,max(date_sent),mailing
FROM contact_copy
WHERE type="EMAIL"
group BY master_id
;
```

I get an UNEXPECTED result:

```
master_id   max(date_sent)  mailing
00001   2015-03-23 21:42:03 ThankYou.html
```

So my question: why is it returning the WRONG MAILING?

It's making me nuts! Thanks.

By the way, I'm not a developer, so sorry if I'm breaking some etiquette rule of asking. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because when you use GROUP BY, all the columns have to be aggregate columns, and mailing is not one of them..

You should use a subquery or a join to make it work

```
SELECT master_id,date_sent,mailing
FROM contact_copy cc
JOIN 
( SELECT master_id,max(date_sent)
  FROM contact_copy
  WHERE type="EMAIL"
  group BY master_id
 ) result
ON cc.master_id= result.master_id AND cc.date_sent=result.date_sent
```

Comment: Hallelujah!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an "unexpected" result because of a MySQL specific extension to the `GROUP BY` functionality. The result you're getting is actually expected, according to the MySQL Reference Manual.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html

---

Other database engines would reject your query as invalid... an error along the lines of "`non-aggregate expressions included in the SELECT list not included in the GROUP BY`".)

We can get MySQL to behave like other databases (and return an error for that query) if we include `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` in the SQL mode.

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

---

To get the result you are looking for...

If the `(master_id,type,date_sent)` tuple is UNIQUE in `contact_copy` (that is, if for given values of `master_id` and `type`, there will be no "duplicate" values of `date_sent`), we could use a JOIN operation to retrieve the specified result.

First, we write a query to get the "maximum" `date_sent` for a given `master_id` and `type`. For example:

```
SELECT mc.master_id
     , mc.type
     , MAX(mc.date_sent) AS max_date_sent
  FROM contact_copy mc
 WHERE mc.master_id = '0001' 
   AND mc.type = 'EMAIL'
```

To retrieve the entire row associated with that "maximum" `date_sent`, we can use that query as an inline view. That is, wrap the query text in parens, assign an alias, and then reference that as if it were a table, for example:

```
SELECT c.master_id
     , c.date_sent
     , c.mailing
  FROM ( SELECT mc.master_id
              , mc.type 
              , MAX(mc.date_sent) AS max_date_sent
           FROM contact_copy mc
          WHERE mc.master_id = '0001' 
            AND mc.type = 'EMAIL'
       ) m
  JOIN contact_copy c
    ON c.master_id = m.master_id
   AND c.type      = m.type
   AND c.date_sent = m.max_date_sent
```

Note that if there are multiple rows that have the same values of `master_id`,`type` and `date_sent`, there is potential to return more than one row. You could add a `LIMIT 1` clause to guarantee that you return only one row; which of those rows is returned is indeterminate, without an `ORDER BY` clause before the LIMIT clause.