# Unknown Column when joining tables and using a subquery

Tags: mysql

I've used the following stackoverflow post to try and get a record with the latest date:
[Select info from table where row has max date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date)

I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR, FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, HP.LAST_10_DAYS, HP.YTD_PERF 
FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT HP.SYMBOL, max(TRADE_DATE) as MaxDate 
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP
GROUP BY HP.SYMBOL
) 
HP on HP.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL
```

When I do this though, I get a error message saying the following:

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'HP.LAST_10_DAYS' in 'field list'

Why would this be the case since HP is defined and it's a field in that table?

Answer (score 2):

because you are doing a join on a select statement not the table "FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE" you cannot use HP on the global select because HP is not defined there

```
SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR, FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, HP.LAST_10_DAYS, HP.YTD_PERF  #3- you cannot use HP here
FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
LEFT JOIN (
# 1- you are not doing ajoin on the table FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP
# 2- you can use HP on this select 
SELECT HP.SYMBOL, max(TRADE_DATE) as MaxDate 
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP
GROUP BY HP.SYMBOL
) 
HP on HP.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL 
JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOLenter code here
```

add the field to the select statement in the join part now they will exist on the result HP  and try to use different alias for the select

```
SELECT AR_SQ.SYMBOL, AR_SQ.NAME, AR_SQ.LAST, FF_PS.SECTOR, FF_PS.SECTOR_TAGS, RS.LAST_10_DAYS, RS.YTD_PERF 
FROM AR_STOCK_QUOTE AR_SQ 
LEFT JOIN (
# add the last_10_days to the fields of you select statement now you can select them
SELECT HP.SYMBOL, max(TRADE_DATE) as MaxDate ,HP.LAST_10_DAYS, HP.YTD_PERF 
FROM FF_HISTORICAL_STOCK_PRICE HP
GROUP BY HP.SYMBOL
) RS on RS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL  #HP is a result of select statement 
JOIN FF_PRIMARY_STOCK_TABLE FF_PS on FF_PS.SYMBOL = AR_SQ.SYMBOL
```

Comment: How would I do this correctly then to access the values in that table?

Comment: I always try to use different aliases for values inside of a SELECT statement and when JOINing the SELECT statement for just this reason. SQL queries are already confusing/ convoluted enough.

Comment: You have to include the LAST_10_DAYS column when doing the SELECT inside of the LEFT JOIN (as well as include it in the GROUP BY or use it in an aggregate function).

Comment: ok i edited the answer with some comment how that you understand i have a poor english sorry