# how to display an element which was posted the earliest?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
tableName

|name    | header | date      |
|--------|--------|-----------|
|abc     | def    | 2016-08-16|
|pqr     | xyz    | 2015-11-20|
```

I wanted to write a query to display the name which was entered the earliest.

`select name from tableName where date(date) = min(date)` encountered an error.

I searched the internet for answers but couldn't find what I was looking for. Any advice and help on this matter would be welcome.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Answer here is applicable to your question (swap max with min)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date/19433107#19433107    Might be overkill, baao's answer is good.

Answer (score 3):

Use `order by` and `limit`

```
SELECT `name` 
FROM tableName 
ORDER BY `date`
LIMIT 1
```

Note that `name` as well as `date` are [mysql keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html), so you shouldn't use them as a column name.

Comment: They may be keywords, but they're not reserved, so their use as column names is fine in my book.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I wrote **shouldn't**. @Strawberry . It's no error for sure, but I try to avoid using keywords as it's only confusing... select date(date) sounds strange to me.

Comment: Well sure, because in that context `date` would be a datetime ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
select name from tableName where date(date) = (select min(date) from tableName)
```