# Finding row with max values in two groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012,
I have a following table:
`id, name, surname, timestamp, type`

`type` has two possible values: `1` and `2`.

Now, I would like to find two rows - for each group (`1` and `2`) row with maximal value in particular `type`.

The problem is that I would like to find  both `name` and `surname`.
I can do it with `SELECT TOP 1 - WHERE ORDER BY - UNION` approach, but I would like to find antother, better idea.
Can you help me ?

Comment: Can you give some sample data and the desired output? Will make it easier to give a more accurate answer.

Comment: variation of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date/19433107#19433107 I believe

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want the most recent for each row, for each type. If that's the case, here is a way with `row_number()`

```
with cte as(
select
    id
    ,name
    ,surname
    ,timestamp
    ,type
    RN = row_number() over (partition by id,type order by timestamp desc))

select *
from cte
where RN = 1
```