# TSQL Show greatest Parcel# from row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have data that looks like this.

[image]

```
Select distinct 
    x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID], x.filname, 
    c.mv_30day_value '30 Day Value As Is', 
    c.mv_30day_repvalue '30 Day Value Repaired', 
    t.parcel 'Parcel#',x. * 
from 
    Resnet_Reporting_ops.dbo.Ops_FullExportFLATV3 as X (NOLOCK) 
left join 
    resnet_mysql.dbo.form_tax t (nolock) on x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID] = t.property_id
left join 
    resnet_mysql.dbo.form_fm c (nolock) on t.task_id = c.task_id
where 
    X.[PropertyBasics.Property Basics - ResID] = 217 
    and x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID] = 1153829
```

How do you get this data to only show 1 record for Parcel #?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432913/select-info-from-table-where-row-has-max-date/19433107#19433107     Should be able to use the logic there, instead of maxdate use max parcel #

Comment: Which version of SQL? 2008 or 2012, you have both tags. Which parcel are you trying to get? I see some have dashes, I assume you want those removed for this. But your 30 day values aren't the same anyway, so which of those would you want?

Comment: Explain the logic, we are good but not mind readers.

Comment: Well If I use maxdate then I have to include a group by clause. In this case I want to retrieve all rows that has a MAX Parcel #. I want the largest Parcel number

Comment: why not use TOP 1, to display the row

Comment: Define `MAX Parcel #` because that is a string

Comment: Please don't use "images of data"! Would you enjoy receiving an answer as the image of the sql query? (How frustrating would all that re-typing be?)

Answer (score 0):

`select distinct` tests the ENTIRE row to see if it is unique. Just the smallest little difference in any column will make a row "distinct". The following 2 values are different, so that will cause 2 rows

1. 741722064100000
2. 741-722-06-41-00000

and the following 2 value pairs are different, which cause 2 more rows:

3. 500000 800000
4. 435000 850000

in all that combines to make 4 rows.

So, it looks like we could strip the dash from data item 2 above, and that would make it equal data item 1.

```
replace(t.parcel,'-','') AS [Parcel#]
```

But is that always true? Could there be other differences in other rows not shown here?

How do we decide between the value pairs 3. or 4. ? `MAX()`won't work e.g.

```
MAX(c.mv_30day_value), MAX(c.mv_30day_repvalue)
```

would produce

```
500000 8500000
```

and that combination doesn't exist in the source data

The logic required to meet the expected result isn't well defined.

Try the following:

```
SELECT
        x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID]
      , x.filname
      , MAX(c.mv_30day_value)     "30 Day Value As Is"
      , MAX(c.mv_30day_repvalue)  "30 Day Value Repaired"
      , replace(t.parcel,'-','')  "Parcel#"

      -- , x.* NO WAY !!

FROM Resnet_Reporting_ops.dbo.Ops_FullExportFLATV3 AS X
LEFT JOIN resnet_mysql.dbo.form_tax t ON x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID] = t.property_id
LEFT JOIN resnet_mysql.dbo.form_fm c ON t.task_id = c.task_id
WHERE X.[PropertyBasics.Property Basics - ResID] = 217
AND x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID] = 1153829
GROUP BY
        x.[PropertyBasics.PK Resnet Property ID]
      , x.filname
      , replace(t.parcel,'-','')
;
```

Note. `x.*` isn't feasible with GROUP BY as you need to specify the columns will define each unique row. `x.*` is also counter productive with "select distinct" as for each additional column of output you increase the possibility of more rows. (i.e. more columns generally = more differences = more rows). Also as mentioned doubt MAX() produces a good result here.

Comment: Is your question solved now? Do you still have questions about this answer?