# MySQL - How can I SELECT rows with MAX date

Tags: php, mysql, date, max

My table is:

```
id_clocking | project_id | date       | comments        | next_steps | dependencies
1           | 39         | 2014-08-01 | new_com         | step1      | dependency1
2           | 39         | 2014-08-10 | NULL            | step2      | NULL
3           | 39         | 2014-08-12 | NULL            | step3      | dependencyx
4           | 39         | 2014-08-05 | commentx        | stepx      | depend
5           | 42         | 2014-07-15 | NULL            | NULL       | dependency_3
6           | 42         | 2014-07-03 | comment_3       | step_c     | dependency_4
7           | 42         | 2014-08-01 | NULL            | step_d     | NULL
```

I need to create a PHP output from the MySQL database by selecting the newest comments, next_steps, dependencies holding the maximum value of the date for each project_id

**Result would be:**

```
 project_id | comments  | next_steps | dependencies
 ------------ ------------------------------------
    39      | commentx  | step3      | dependencyx
    42      | comment_3 | step_d     | dependency_3
```

And should return only the rows with values based on the highest date where available (where we have ----- there is no value and that rows should not be considered) 
Could you please share your ideas?

Comment: And should return only the rows with values based on the highest date where available (where we have ----- there is no value and that rows should not be considered)

Comment: Please take 5 minutes and read this page http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. And improve your question readability.

Comment: "----" should (probably) be NULL

Comment: yes that is correct ---- should be NULL

Comment: Why is id 42 with dependency_3 in the result? should't it be "-------" ?

Comment: Why not this row? -> `6 | 42 | 2014-07-03 | comment_3 | step_c | dependency_4`

Comment: Ah, you mean you're only ignoring NULL dependencies? So, NULL next_steps are OK?

Comment: Hm, no. That can't be right either !?!?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this link below:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is MASSIVELY over-convoluted - but I seem to be having a senior moment, so...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id_clocking INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,project_id INT NOT NULL
 ,date        DATE NOT NULL
 ,comments        VARCHAR(20) NULL
 ,next_steps VARCHAR(20) NULL
 ,dependencies VARCHAR(20) NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,39,'2014-08-01','new_com','step1','dependency1'),
 (2,39,'2014-08-10',NULL,'step2',NULL),
 (3,39,'2014-08-12',NULL,'step3','dependencyx'),
 (4,39,'2014-08-05','commentx','stepx','depend'),
 (5,42,'2014-07-15',NULL,NULL,'dependency_3'),
 (6,42,'2014-07-03','comment_3','step_c','dependency_4'),
 (7,42,'2014-08-01',NULL,'step_d',NULL);

 SELECT i.project_id
      , j.comments
      , k.next_steps
      , l.dependencies
   FROM 
      ( SELECT project_id
             , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'comment' THEN max_date END) comment_date
             , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'next_steps' THEN max_date END) next_steps_date
             , MAX(CASE WHEN type = 'dependencies' THEN max_date END) dependencies_date
          FROM 
             ( SELECT a.project_id
                    , a.type
                    , MAX(a.date) max_date
                 FROM 
                    ( SELECT project_id
                           , date
                           , 'comment' type
                           , comments FROM my_table 
                       WHERE comments IS NOT NULL
                       UNION
                      SELECT project_id
                           , date
                           , 'next_steps' 
                           , next_steps 
                        FROM my_table 
                       WHERE next_steps IS NOT NULL
                       UNION
                      SELECT project_id
                           , date
                           , 'dependencies' 
                           , dependencies 
                        FROM my_table 
                       WHERE dependencies IS NOT NULL
                    ) a
                GROUP
                   BY project_id
                    , type
             ) m
         GROUP
            BY project_id
      ) i
   JOIN my_table j
     ON j.project_id = i.project_id 
    AND j.date = i.comment_date
   JOIN my_table k
     ON k.project_id = i.project_id 
    AND k.date = i.next_steps_date
   JOIN my_table l
     ON l.project_id = i.project_id 
    AND l.date = i.dependencies_date;

 +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
 | project_id | comments  | next_steps | dependencies |
 +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
 |         39 | commentx  | step3      | dependencyx  |
 |         42 | comment_3 | step_d     | dependency_3 |
 +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

This seems like a simpler solution... (and faster too: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9552e/5)

```
SELECT x.project_id
     , c.comments
     , n.next_steps
     , d.dependencies
  FROM 
     ( SELECT project_id
            , MAX(CASE WHEN comments IS NOT NULL THEN date END) comments_date
            , MAX(CASE WHEN next_steps IS NOT NULL THEN date END) next_steps_date
            , MAX(CASE WHEN dependencies IS NOT NULL THEN date END) dependencies_date 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY project_id
     ) x
  JOIN my_table c
    ON c.project_id = x.project_id
   AND c.date = x.comments_date
  JOIN my_table n
    ON n.project_id = x.project_id
   AND n.date = x.next_steps_date
  JOIN my_table d
    ON d.project_id = x.project_id
   AND d.date = x.dependencies_date
 WHERE c.comments IS NOT NULL
   AND n.next_steps IS NOT NULL
   AND d.dependencies IS NOT NULL;

   +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
   | project_id | comments  | next_steps | dependencies |
   +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
   |         39 | commentx  | step3      | dependencyx  |
   |         42 | comment_3 | step_d     | dependency_3 |
   +------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Looks even more complicated than my solution, but both are working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9552e/3). I renamed `my_table` to `example8`. +1 for your work

Comment: The execution plan of your new one looks best of all, see [newest Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9552e/7). I've added one solution with joins but the result didn't impress me.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question you want to every project_id

- the newest comments item that is not null
- the newest next_steps item that is not null
- the newest dependencies item that is not null

Those items can be from different rows. If that's the case you could do it with this query:

```
SELECT
    project_id,
    (SELECT e2.comments FROM example8 e2 WHERE e2.date = (
        SELECT MAX(date) FROM example8 e1 
        WHERE e1.comments IS NOT NULL and e2.project_id = e1.project_id
        GROUP BY e1.project_id )
     AND e.project_id = e2.project_id) as comments,
    (SELECT e2.next_steps FROM example8 e2 WHERE e2.date = (
        SELECT MAX(date) FROM example8 e1 
        WHERE e1.next_steps IS NOT NULL and e2.project_id = e1.project_id
        GROUP BY e1.project_id )
     AND e.project_id = e2.project_id) as next_steps,
    (SELECT e2.dependencies FROM example8 e2 WHERE e2.date = (
        SELECT MAX(date) FROM example8 e1 
        WHERE e1.dependencies IS NOT NULL and e2.project_id = e1.project_id
        GROUP BY e1.project_id )
     AND e.project_id = e2.project_id) as dependencies
FROM     example8 e
GROUP BY e.project_id;
```

**[Demo: Solutions of Strawberry and mine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9552e/3)**

Comment: Yay - mine's faster! :-)

Comment: @me_sleepin I have to say that Strawberrys second solution is the best. So it would only be fair that you accept his answer. Please do so.

Answer (score -1):

To get results run this query:

    `SELECT *
    FROM tableName AS a
    WHERE date = (
        SELECT MAX(date)
        FROM tableName AS b
    )`

Answer (score -1):

The query shown below should work:

```
Select 
    tableA.project_id, comments, next_steps, dependencies
from
    tableA,
    (select 
        max(date) date, project_id
    from
        tableA
    group by project_id) tableB
WHERE
    tableA.date = tableB.date
        AND tableA.project_id = tableB.project_id;
```

Please change column and table names as you need.

Comment: Again, a good solution for a different problem... although some of us try to discourage 'implicit' (comma-) join syntax.