# SQL - Get max date from dd/mm/yyyy formated column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have db table which have column name `STATUSDATE`. Type of this column is varchar2 and that column already have data in dd/mm/yyyy format. And i want get the recent date(max date). I used max() method for this but it not give the correct result, 
as example consider following dates

31/08/2014

01/09/2016

after using max(STATUSDATE) the result is 31/08/2014. I'm using oracle db.

I'm try to use following quarry but since above problem its give incorrect results

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE t
inner join (
    select CLIENTNAME, max(STATUSDATE) as MaxDate
    from FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
    group by CLIENTNAME
) tm on t.CLIENTNAME = tm.CLIENTNAME and t.STATUSDATE = tm.MaxDate
```

please can anyone suggest proper way to do this 
Thank You

Comment: Is it too late to just fix the column type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate

Comment: Yes I cant fix the column type..

Comment: i think you cant use max without changing the column type, but you can do what you want in a hard way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moral:  Don't store dates as strings.  Databases have built-in types for a reason.

So, convert to a proper date and take the max, but you don't need a `JOIN` for this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by client_name
                          order by to_date(statusdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') desc
                         ) as seqnum
      from my_db.my_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: this quarry gives different result, but it still have the problem that I have mention in the question

Comment: it is given 2014 data instead of 2016 data

Comment: @Kani . . . I misread the question.  For the maximum date, use `desc`  on the `order by` rather than the default `asc`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `inner join`. You can do simply that:

```
select CLIENTNAME, desnse_rank() over (partition by client_name order by statusdate desc ) as MaxDate
FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
where maxdate =1
group by CLIENTNAME
```

Comment: Your quarry gives this error >> ERROR: ORA-00904: "MAXDATE": invalid identifier