# SQL Server find most recent date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, aggregate

I have a `tableA` of date ranges:

```
tranid    item    startdate     enddate
---------------------------------------
1          A      1/1/2000      2/2/2005
2          A      5/1/2000      2/2/2005
3          B      7/8/2015      9/8/2015
4          C      4/10/2007     7/20/2008
5          C      4/10/2003     7/20/2005
```

How to write a SQL query to only select the most recent transactions (ex the most recent start and end dates)?

For example, for A, the most recent date range is 5/1/2000 to 2/2/2005 and for C, the most recent date range is C 4/10/2007 to 7/20/2008.

I am at a complete loss to write this because it seems easy but is not.

```
select item, max(enddate), max(startdate)
from tableA 
where max(enddate)
group by item, enddate, startdate
```

SQL Server returned an error related to 'having' on something like that - a problem with aggregates.

gracias :)

Comment: what if one row has a maximum start date and another has a maximum end date?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)

Answer (score 2):

You have a `where max(enddate)` which doesn't make sense, also you don't need to include startdate/enddate in your group by, just the item, so try:

```
select item, max(enddate), max(startdate)
from tableA
group by item
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
:with cte as
(
Select Row_Number() Over(Partition by item order by startdate desc) RN,*
From yourtable 
)
Select * 
From cte 
Where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical arg-max problem: where you want rows with most recent start date.

You need to split the problem into two steps:

1. calculate the most recent start date for each item.
2. join the maximum result with the original table to obtain the desirable rows.

Solution:

```
SELECT b.tranid, b.item, a.maxstartdate, b.enddate
FROM
  (SELECT t.item, MAX(t.startdate) maxstartdate
   FROM t
   GROUP BY t.item) a
JOIN t b
ON a.maxstartdate = b.startdate AND a.item = b.item;
```

Hope this can help you! :)