# I Want to get second entry date-time wise

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get second entry in SQL

```
Consgno     Name      Entrydatetime

 111          A     01/03/2017 10:10:15
 111          A     01/03/2017 10:20:15
 111          A     01/03/2017 11:10:20
 222          B     02/03/2017 10:10:25
 222          B     02/03/2017 11:10:36
 333          C     06/03/2017 10:10:25
 333          C     07/03/2017 10:10:12
 444          D     04/03/2017 10:10:41
 444          D     04/03/2017 01:10:20
 444          D     06/03/2017 10:10:32
```

One Consgno has entered more than one time.
And I want to output like this:

```
   Consgno  Name     Entrydatetime
    111      A      01/03/2017 10:20:15
    222      B      02/03/2017 11:10:36
    333      C      07/03/2017 10:10:12
    444      D      04/03/2017 01:10:20
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)

Comment: Column data type? Is the format MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: Column Entrydatetime type is  DD/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 1):

sql server/oracle/Postgres:

```
with CTE as
(
select MyTable.*, row_number() over(partition by consgno order by entrydatetime) as rn
from MyTable
)
select *
from CTE
where rn = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

(Works only, if you DB supports window analytic functions)

In case, if there is chance that `Entrydatetime` may repeated for same `Consgno`, and you want second `date-time wise`, then you can use:

```
select * from (
    select   MyTable.*, 
    dense_rank() over(partition by consgno order by entrydatetime) as rnk,
    row_number() over(partition by consgno,entrydatetime order by entrydatetime) as rn
    from MyTable
) t
where  rnk = 2 and rn = 1
```

(Note, that if `consgno`  have same `Entrydatetime` for every row, this query not returns that `consgno` at all.)

Answer (score -1):

Use OFFSET command in your query eg.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  Consgno,Name,Entrydatetime  FROM tbl_test ORDER BY
    Consgno
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;
```

This example selects the 2nd row.
The Consgno has to be DISTINCT

Comment: Surely you need to add `Entrydatetime` into the `order by`?

Comment: Why `SELECT DISTINCT` when `LIMIT 1`? (Btw, are you sure OP is using a dbms that support that vendor specific `LIMIT`?)

Comment: either way..it will work without `LIMIT` for DBMS which support `DISTINCT`. Just giving a general solution

Answer (score -2):

You can refer my query. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
With CTE
AS
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Consgno order by Consgno) as Number
from Test)

select * from CTE where Number = 2
```

Comment: Wrong `order by` based on expected output

Comment: @JohnHC: I have tested and it returned output as expected, my friend!

Comment: This time, yes. Over a larger dataset this will not guarantee that it will return the second occurence (by date) that OP has implied with the expected output

Comment: @JohnHC. Yeah, you're right. But he said he want to get second entry in SQL, not depend on Entrydatetime field.