# Row_number over partition and find the max rn value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I started from the following table:

```
+---+-----+---------+----------+----------+-------------+
| 1 | ID  | OrderNO | PartCode | Quantity | DateEntered |
| 2 | 417 | 2144    | 44917    | 100      | 40773       |
| 3 | 418 | 7235    | 11762    | 5        | 40773       |
| 4 | 419 | 9999    | 60657    | 100      | 40773       |
| 5 | 420 | 9999    | 60657    | 90       | 40774       |
+---+-----+---------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

to this:

```
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------------+----+
| 1 | OrderNO | PartCode | Quantity | DateEntered | rn |
| 2 | 2144    | 44917    | 100      | 40773       | 1  |
| 3 | 7235    | 11762    | 5        | 40773       | 1  |
| 4 | 9999    | 60657    | 100      | 40773       | 1  |
| 5 | 9999    | 60657    | 90       | 40774       | 2  |
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------------+----+
```

using the query fo this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118233/1008588).

```
select OrderNO,PartCode,Quantity,row_number() over(partition by OrderNO order by DateEntered desc) as rn
from YourTable) as T
```

Now, I am trying to add a field "rn_max", shich is the max "rn" of each OrderNO and get the following result:

```
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------------+----+--------+
| 1 | OrderNO | PartCode | Quantity | DateEntered | rn | rn_max |
| 2 | 2144    | 44917    | 100      | 40773       | 1  | 1      |
| 3 | 7235    | 11762    | 5        | 40773       | 1  | 1      |
| 4 | 9999    | 60657    | 100      | 40773       | 1  | 2      |
| 5 | 9999    | 60657    | 90       | 40774       | 2  | 2      |
+---+---------+----------+----------+-------------+----+--------+
```

I could get this result calculating the max of each OrderNO with the query

```
SELECT OrderNO,MAX(rn) AS 'rn_max'
FROM (
select OrderNO,PartCode,Quantity,row_number() over(partition by OrderNO order by DateEntered desc) as rn
from YourTable
) T
Group by OrderNO
```

and then use a left join from YourTable.
Is there a shortest way to count the rows with the same OderNo? I've tried to add `row_number() over(partition by OrderNO) as rn_max` at the query but I need to write an order by clause.

Comment: Looks like you'd be better off using COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNO)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `max` window function.

```
SELECT T.*,MAX(rn) OVER(PARTITION BY OrderNo) AS rn_max
FROM (
select OrderNO,PartCode,Quantity,row_number() over(partition by OrderNO order by DateEntered desc) as rn
from YourTable
) T
```

Edit: An easier option is to use `count` as suggested by @Jason A. Long in the comments.

```
select OrderNO
       ,PartCode
       ,Quantity
       ,row_number() over(partition by OrderNO order by DateEntered desc) as rn
       ,count(*) over(partition by OrderNO) as maxrn
from YourTable
```

Comment: sorry forgot to remove `group by` from op's query.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.
Basically you'd use max() aggregation over the partitioned rows to get the rn_max

```
select *, max(rn) over(partition by OrderNO)  as rn_max
FROM (
select OrderNO,PartCode,Quantity,row_number() over(partition by OrderNO order by DateEntered desc) as rn
from YourTable
) T
```