# Select row with latest date from a multi join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble getting the 1 row with the latest date out of a multi-join statement.

3 tables involved:

(Unit)

```
SN                |            DateTime |
------------------|---------------------|
123               |2018-03-10 15:23:32  |
456               |2018-03-10 15:40:15  |
789               |2018-03-10 15:53:58  |
```

(History)

```
ID     |SN                |
-------|------------------|
84     |123               |
85     |456               |
86     |789               |
```

(Link)

```
SN                |      ID |
------------------|---------|
123               |84       |
456               |85       |
789               |86       |
```

(Station)

```
ID     |Type            |      datetime      |location                 |
-------|----------------|--------------------|-------------------------|
84     |ALPHA           |2017-08-21 16:54:23 |X                        |
84     |BRAVO           |2017-08-21 16:56:08 |X1                       |
277    |DELTA           |2017-08-21 17:46:11 |Y                        |
```

**Goal**

Get a joined table that will only show those rows with the most recent datetime per row and type selected.

I have managed to join up the tables, even sort the datetimes so that the most recent date is always the top 1, but I have no clue how then to select this top 1 I am interested in.

I have been at this now for several days no and cannot get only the one row that I need. I always end up with duplicates such as (Station) ID 84.

**What I have tried before**

```
SELECT rs.Unit, max(rf2.Type) as mydate,  rf2.Type, rf2.ID
FROM DB.dbo.Unit rs 
INNER JOIN DB.dbo.Link rf ON ( rs.ID = rf.ID  )  
INNER JOIN DB.dbo.History rf1 ON ( rf.SN = rf1.SN)  
INNER JOIN DB.dbo.Station rf2 ON ( rf1.ID = rf2.ID )         
where rf2.Type like 'AL%'
GROUP BY rs.SN, rf2.DateTime, rf2.Type, rf2.ID
order by rs.SN, rf2.DateTime desc;
```

I also tried a CTE, but same problem: I do not know how to only keep the most recent rows.

**Result of above**

```
SN                |mydate               |Type         |ID     |
------------------|---------------------|-------------|-------|
666               |2017-09-23 15:15:58  |Alpha        |189    |
777               |2017-09-01 16:13:16  |Alpha7       |138    |
*123*             |*2017-11-03 09:17:51*|*Alpha1*     |*84*   |
123               |2017-11-01 03:08:09  |Alpha2       |84     |
123               |2017-11-01 03:07:59  |Alpha3       |84     |
```

Basically what I would need is a table that only keeps unique rows such as the one marked with stars (*123*), most recent date, specific Type as in 'like 'AL%'.

After @Ferc's comment I tried something like this:

```
select ts.ID, ts.DateTime, ts.location 
from (select ID, DateTime, location 
row_number() over(partition by ID order by DateTime desc) as rn
from DB.dbo.Station where station like 'AL%') as ts
where rn = 1; 

I got "SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near '('.
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Incorrect syntax near '('." 
as an (complete rubbish) error message.
```

**I then put a ',' after *location* and got a result.**

I will try to incorporate this into my CTE.

Comment: Instead of a `group by`, you can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118233/1733214)

Comment: Could you show us your expect result from your sample data?Becasue **Result of above** can't match your sample data.What's the diffrent between History and Link table?

Comment: @Ferc: Thanks for the link. I had seen something like this before, but never got it to work. Updated the question with what I tried. I only get an error near: '('. Whatever that is supposed to mean....

Comment: @Just_Stacking Ok... well, perhaps you had a syntax error somewhere. IT WeiHan seems to have the syntax right, but I think for your case, you'd need to partition by `[Type]` or `[SN]`, not the date field.

Comment: @Ferc: Yes, correct. I managed to figure this out. Thanks! IT WeiHan's answer seems to work perfectly when I change the dummy names with my real table names. Also getting all other fields from the other tables seems to work fine, so that I end up with one big, happy table. I think I will keep this as the answer ,since it was the quickest to arrive.

Comment: @D-Shih: Thanks, for pointing that out. The "Hierarchy" of tables was same as the order they came in, so simply joining them works to get to the required table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
    select 
    row_number() over(partition by rf2.[datetime] order by rf2.[datetime] desc) as rn 
    ,rf2.*
    FROM Unit rs 
    INNER JOIN Link rf ON ( rs.SN = rf.SN  )  
    INNER JOIN History rf1 ON ( rf.SN = rf1.SN)  
    INNER JOIN Station rf2 ON ( rf1.ID = rf2.ID )  
    where rf2.Type like 'AL%'
) T
where rn = 1;
```

[image]

---

[SQL Fiddle Example Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88a88/5/0)

Comment: Thanks for including the Fiddle! I was not aware that they had a service for this now as well, only knew about the .NET one. Got more than I looked for! :]

Comment: it's my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you might do like this.

You need to write a subquery with `ROW_NUMBER` with `OVER(partition by rf2.ID,rs.SN order by rf2.[datetime] desc)` you will get the group number on `rf2.ID` and `rs.SN`.

Then getting the `RowNumber = 1` row,which mean newest date.

```
SELECT t.SN,t.[datetime],t.Type,t.ID
FROM(
  SELECT rs.SN,
         rf2.[datetime],
         rf2.[Type],
         rf2.ID,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by rf2.ID,rs.SN order by rf2.[datetime] desc) rn
  FROM Unit rs 
  INNER JOIN Link rf ON ( rs.SN = rf.SN  )  
  INNER JOIN History rf1 ON ( rf.SN = rf1.SN)  
  INNER JOIN Station rf2 ON ( rf1.ID = rf2.ID )         
  WHERE rf2.Type like 'AL%'
) t 
where t.rn = 1
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/36061/2*