# How to get common date using distinct or group by in sql server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get common data using distinct or group by clause in sql server 2012
where my Createddate is the latest

below is the table i have

[image]

below is the query i have used to get the common TargetsDate2

```
select distinct convert(VARCHAR(15),TargetDate,106) as TargetDate2,TargetDate 
From LogsObservRequestActivity 
Where LogsObservRequestActivity.ActivityID=170 
and not TargetDate is null 
and isnull(TargetDate,'')<>isnull(TargetDateOriginal,'')
```

i am able to get common Targetdate2 
but i want to order it by createdon desc, i have tried using order by clause but i do not get the expected result, i get all the dates if use order by clause

below is the expected output

[image]

Comment: Can You Specify Example for the Output you need

Comment: @TanveerSinghBhatia out has been updated in my post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` function, but i would use `subquery` :

```
select l.* 
from LogActivity l 
where TargetDate is not null and 
      LogActivityID = (select top 1 LogActivityID 
                       from LogActivity 
                       where ActivityID = l.ActivityID and
                             TargetDate2 = l.TargetDate2
                       order by CreatedOn DESC);
```

By, analytical function you can also achieve the same

```
select top (1) with ties, *
from LogActivity l 
where TargetDate is not null 
order by row_number() over (partition by ActivityID, TargetDate2 order by CreatedOn DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want only Highest **createdOn** column value for each **Targetdate2** column, then use **@Yogesh Sharma** query

Else If you want all **createdOn** Column value for each **Targetdate2** column then use this query

```
select distinct convert(VARCHAR(15),TargetDate,106) as TargetDate2,
       TargetDate 
       From LogsObservRequestActivity 
       Where LogsObservRequestActivity.ActivityID=170 
       and not TargetDate is null 
       and isnull(TargetDate,'')<>isnull(TargetDateOriginal,'') 
order by row_number() over (partition by ActivityID, TargetDate2 order by CreatedOn DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query...

```
SELECT sq.logactivityid, 
       sq.targetdate2, 
       t1.createdon, 
       t1.activityid 
FROM   tablename t1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(logactivityid) AS LogActivityID, 
                          targetdate2 
                   FROM   tablename 
                   GROUP  BY targetdate2) sq 
               ON t1.logactivityid = sq.logactivityid 
--WHERE  activityid = 170 
ORDER  BY t1.createdon
```

Note: This will not work as expected when `logactivityid` column has duplicate values. Therefore, please make sure `logactivityid` has unique values.

*If I'm misunderstood, please let me know.*

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query using window functions as:

```
select top (1) with ties convert(VARCHAR(15), TargetDate,106) as TargetDate2, TargetDate 
From LogsObservRequestActivity l
Where LogsObservRequestActivity.ActivityID = 170 and
      TargetDate is not null
      (TargetDate <> TargetDateOriginal and not (TargetDate is null and TargetDateOriginal is not null)
      )
order by row_number() over (partition by cast(TargetDate as date) order by TargetDate desc);
```

Notes:

- The `TOP (1) WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()` negate the need for `SELECT DISTINCT`.
- `NOT <x> IS NULL` is much less common than `<X> IS NOT NULL`.
- I'm not a big fan of using `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` for the comparison you are making.  For one thing, one argument is a string and one is a `datetime`.  Do you even now if the the result is a string or `datetime`?
- In databases other than SQL Server, the typical solution would be `ROW_NUMBER()` in a subquery.