# How to get single SQL row with latest Date + Time without considering irrelevant columns with different data?

Tags: sql

In my SQL query I'm trying to get data from database that has the newest combination of Date and Time for each Project No.

My formula is:

```
select [Project], [Machine], [Category], [Details], MAX(date  + ' ' + time) as [DateTime] 
from [SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC] group by [Project No], [Machine], [Repair Category], [Details]
```

Here is a part of the search result

```
| Project | Machine | Category |   Details   |         DateTime         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| M00004  |   A09   |    QC    | CENTER OVER |  2020-01-21 19:15:00.000 |
| M00004  |   A09   |    QC    |  FIRST CUT  |  2020-01-21 19:00:00.000 |
| M00006  |   C03   |    QC    |  PUSHER UP  |  2020-01-21 17:30:00.000 |
```

The query ends up giving me 2 rows of `M00004` because Details is different. What I really wanted is for the table to return me 1 row for each Project.

```
| Project | Machine | Category |   Details   |         DateTime         |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| M00004  |   A09   |    QC    | CENTER OVER |  2020-01-21 19:15:00.000 |
| M00006  |   C03   |    QC    |  PUSHER UP  |  2020-01-21 17:30:00.000 |
```

How  do I tell the formula to only show me the latest entry only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate an ordered list of the values for each `Project` according to `Datetime` descending, and then select only the rows which have row number = 1:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category], 
         [Details], date  + ' ' + time as [DateTime] 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Project] ORDER BY (date  + ' ' + time) DESC) AS rn
  FROM [SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC]
)
SELECT [Project], [Machine], [Category], [Details],  [DateTime] 
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use where not exists

```
select [Project], [Machine], [Category], [Details],  [DateTime] 
from [SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC] a
where not exists(
select 1 
from [SQL].[dbo].[ZMAC] b where a.Machine  = b.Machine  and a.[DateTime] < b.[DateTime] 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a related answer with the link below for the MAX(DATE)....

[SQL Server: SELECT only the rows with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118170/sql-server-select-only-the-rows-with-maxdate)