# Returning only most recent audit rows using concatenation of other columns to find the correct grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am stuck on what I thought would be a fairly straightforward query in SQL Server (I'm using 2018)

I have a table (AUDIT_TABLE) that I have read only access to which looks like this:

| ID | DimensionA | DimensionB | DimensionC | Amount | UserID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | DEF | GHI | 100 | Mark | 2022/01/01 12:00:00 |
| 2 | ABC | DEF | GHI | 10 | James | 2022/01/01 06:00:00 |
| 3 | ABC | DEF | GHI | 250 | Mark | 2022/01/01 02:00:00 |
| 4 | JKL | MNO | PQR | 250 | Bob | 2022/01/01 13:00:00 |
| 5 | JKL | MNO | PQR | 100 | Dave | 2022/01/01 12:00:00 |

What I'm trying to find is the most recent entries in an audit table and the grouping needs to be determined by combining multiple columns. eg All rows where (Dimension A + Dimension B + Dimension C) are the same are considered to be the same record and we want to find the most recent entry to it. In the table above IDs 1, 2 & 3 are the same (ABC+DEF+GHI), and IDs 4 & 5 are the same (JKL+MNO+PQR).

So using the above example table I am trying to write a select statement to return this result:

| Dimension A | Dimension B | Dimension C | Amount | UserID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | DEF | GHI | 100 | Mark | 2022/01/01 12:00:00 |
| JKL | MNO | PQR | 250 | Bob | 2022/01/01 13:00:00 |

I have tried this query (amongst many other combinations) and just can't get the result I'm after:

```
SELECT DimensionA, DimensionB, DimensionC, Amount, 
UserID, Max(Timestamp), (DimensionA + DimensionB + DimensionC) AS POV
FROM AUDIT_TABLE
GROUP BY POV
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```sql
select DimensionA,
       DimensionB,
       DimensionC,Amount,UserID,TimeStamp
from (select DimensionA,
             DimensionB,
             DimensionC,Amount,UserID,TimeStamp,
             row_number() over(partition by DimensionA,DimensionB,DimensionC order by Timestamp desc) as rn
      from AUDIT_TABLE ) as T
where rn = 1
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1d44200988e858ba5beae11702cb6bc6)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7118233/2820150)

Comment: Thank you that is spot on :-)
row_number() over(partition by ) is exactly what i've been looking for but just couldnt find in my Google searches.

Comment: [mssql max date row values](https://www.google.com/search?q=mssql+max+date+row+values&oq=mssql+max+date+row+values) 1st result Welcome mate :)